# AWS CDK Lambda Layer Python Package

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

Currently when I create a Python Lambda Layer using the following CDK code:

```
_lambda.LayerVersion(
            self,
            "CommonPythonLambdaLayer",
            code=_lambda.Code.from_asset(
                "src/common",
                bundling=cdk.BundlingOptions(
                    image=lambda_bundling_image,  # type: ignore
                    command=[
                        "bash",
                        "-c",
                        "pip install --no-cache -r requirements.txt --platform manylinux2014_aarch64 --only-binary=:all: --upgrade -t /asset-output/python && cp -au . /asset-output/python",
                    ],
                    platform="linux/arm64",
                ),
            ),
        )
```

The directory structure of src/common/ is:

```
src/
    common/
        models.py
```

The CDK code for the current Lambda layer creates:

```
python/
    models.py
```

However, what I need from the Lambda Layer is:

```
python/
    common/
        models.py
```

Two options I have tried and do not want is:
Set build_dir in the CDK code to "src/" as it has other packages that needs to be excluded.

Modify the asset paths to /common, as then the requirements.txt packages will also get moved to there:

```
pip install --no-cache -r requirements.txt --platform manylinux2014_aarch64 --only-binary=:all: --upgrade -t /asset-output/python/common && cp -au . /asset-output/python/common
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to resolve it by only copying . to /asset-output/python/common

```
pip install --no-cache -r requirements.txt --platform manylinux2014_aarch64 --only-binary=:all: --upgrade -t /asset-output/python && cp -au . /asset-output/python/common
```